# How point my domain to my server?

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, host

I've a problem with my domain. Recently I've purchased mydomain.com and I've configured DNS, by the control panel of my registrar, in record A the "*" and "www" point to my server ip. (It's a home server with Win 7 Pro). The nameservers are default of my domain registrar. Now, I use AMMPS, and I've manually configured virtual host in httpd.conf & httpd-vhosts.conf, and the situation is this:

In httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/"
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/error.err"
CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#DO NOT EDIT, CREATED BY AMPPS


#### mydomain.com VirtualHost ####

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/mydomain.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/mydomain.com"
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/mydomain.com_error.err"
CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/mydomain.com_access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


####################################
```

Now it seems right because when i type in the browser "localhost" it shows the folder www of AMPPS, and when I type www.mydomain.com it shows content of www/mydomain.com

But, If I type in the browser mydomain.com without prefix www., it shows the courtesy page of my domain registrar.

How I can fix this?

Comment: I wonder if the DNS servers need to propagate an update?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes, the changes have been made some days ago...